# Washburn EA15 — Laminate top?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

[Guitar Center](https://www.guitarcenter.com/Washburn/Festival-EA15A-Spruce-Top-With-Flame-Maple-Veneer-Acoustic-Cutaway-Electric-Guitar-With-4-Band-EQ.gc) says "Laminated flamed maple top," but everywhere else, including Washburn's website just say "Flame Maple Top." Anyone know the validity of this?

Comment: Both can be true. Considering the price point I doubt it’s a solid flamed maple top. That much solid flamed maple alone would cost more than the whole guitar. If you look at other guitars on the Washburn site, you’ll see the solid topped guitars actually say “solid” in the specs.

Comment: I see. Would that also apply to Ibanez guitars? I have an AEG12II. On the website it says "spruce top". There's also the AEG200, which is $200 more than the I believe $300 MSRP of the former, which says "Solid Sitka Spruce Top." Ibanez sells their guitars pretty cheap, and I dunno what the price range for solid tops is